# Error: Expected known function, got 'CURDATE' on symfony3.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm  using this functions on a repository class

```
 public function get5DaysOldNotFilledQuestionnaires(){
      
        $raw_query = 'SELECT u.email, u.created 
        FROM  AppBundle:Questionnaire AS q 
        JOIN AppBundle:User AS u 
        WHERE u.is_api_user = 1 
        AND q.weight IS NULL
        AND u.created between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)';
    

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($raw_query);
        $emails_to_remind = $query->getResult();


      return $emails_to_remind;
    }
```

The sql is correct but I get this error when I try to execute the query

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 206: Error: Expected known function, got 'CURDATE'
```

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date() function instead of CURDATE() function or you can use the below code.

```html
function curdate() {
    return date('Y-m-d');
}

// echo the date to screen
echo curdate();
```